# Photoshop Actions

Tags: adobe-photoshop

For some reason, when I am recording an action, when I try to align an object to the top left of the layer, it does not get recorded.  Why is this happening?  Even if I try moving the option with the keyboard arrow keys, it does record it at all.

I am using Adobe Photoshop 7.

Comment: What "object" are you trying to move and align?

Comment: As in a square, rectangle, circle, pasted image from clipboard etc etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't remember if PS 7 had the feature, but try selecting all canvas (ctrl + a), then provided that the object is solid (even if has transparency) and the remaining background of the layer where it is, is transparent, and that you are actually on that layer (selected in layers dialog), then, go to top menu "Layer", then "Align layers to selection", then "Left Edges", then top menu "Layer" again, "Align layers to selection", then "top edges". That should do it.

Comment: I've been trying that, but when I click left edge, the object moves to the left, but no action gets recorded in the actions section except the bit where I clicked ctrl+a...

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop action doesn't record layer selection by clicks. If you're aligning to a specific layer, you have to make the layer selections by keyboard shortcuts within the layer palette. It helps if the two layers being aligned are on top of each other.

Shift + opt(alt) + [ or ]